# When to ask a new question or edit an old question

Tags: support, edits, asking-questions

This is in reference to [my recent ctypes question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35530469/ptrace-reset-a-breakpoint).

After taking a break and fighting with it for a couple more days I found a solution, but I would like to know why.  This happens to me occasionally and I haven't figured out best practice.

Is it better to answer my own question and open a new question asking about why the fix works, or should I edit the original question (with no answers) pointing to the solution and asking why it works.

Comment: "I found a solution, but I would like to know why" -- I wish more programmers were like you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have found an answer to your question you should post it as an answer, not as an edit to the question.

If you have a new question as a result of information you've found while attempting to (and in this case, succeeding at) answering a different question, then you are welcome to ask that as a new question.

You should not be editing your question into a completely different question just because you're no longer interested in the first question, and are now interested in a different question.