# Why is this question off topic?

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions

Why was this questions considered off topic and what needs to be done to make it on-topic for Stack Overflow?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57997174/vb-dotnet-displays-no-such-column-using-sqlite-as-database

Comment: The question when it was closed is https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57997174/revisions

Comment: @EricSchneider As others have said: You have a valid question here, but when you come and attack people (no matter how valid your viewpoint may seem), they sometimes will close, downvote, and delete your question (even though it's on topic here).  I can't do anything about the downvotes, but we can at least edit your question to remove the inflammatory bits and get support for the issue you're having.

Answer (score 24):

The first revision was a textbook case of searching for a textbook:

> I have been searching for vb.net ebooks on sqlite but i am not finding one.Can someone please help me with any Vb.net ebook which focuses more on sqlite.

Whenever you see a question closed that you think shouldn’t be, it helps to see the original one so you know what changed.

---

For what it’s worth, moderator ChrisF says [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/336537/6083675) about (question banned) users who overwrite their  questions:

> Now if the question has no answers it's not really a problem. Yes, it's abuse of the system but no one has been disadvantaged by this and if the new question is any good it might actually help the OP get out of their ban.

(Whether or not you agree with this stance is a discussion for a [different question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/389624/6083675).)

Comment: yes, but he improved question.

Comment: @EricSchneider replacing the question with a different one isn't allowed. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317450

Comment: ok, so tell him, help him, new users don't know all these things

Comment: @EricSchneider Why don't you? You asked, and you're already involved in the comments. Summoning a meta flock is, aside inefficient and slow, unnecessary.

Comment: because I see a new user trying to solve a problem, and I have seen this many times. I didn't know why it was block originally.

Comment: Adding up: No one will stop anyone from providing feedback, but one must _not_ expect people to do it as if it were some kind of duty. It's actually a right not to comment at all.

Comment: @EricSchneider You *do* know why it was blocked initially. It’s a resource request. If you want to guide the user to the rules of the site, *do that*; if you’re not willing, then the “oppressor” in this scenario is *more you than anyone else*. Why should others pick up the burden you yourself are not willing to bear?

Comment: I don't know how or maybe not able to see revisions

Comment: @EricSchneider when a post is edited, it says "Edited x <time frame> ago". It's blue, it's a link, and if you click it, you see revisions. You can also manually find it by going to `https://stackoverflow.com/posts/<post ID>/revisions`

Answer (score -30):

The OP is currently question banned; likely because of the downvotes on their question (it is at -6; likely with the meta attention pushed them over the edge).  The VB.NET "Find me a book on SQLite" question can never be on topic for Stack Overflow; and I'd prefer the user edit that question into a question that can be upvoted, since as it stands they wouldn't be able to get out of their question ban with the question being rolled back to its original revision.

We tell users to fix their questions to get un Q-banned.  In the case of blatant "can never be on topic questions", I'm OK with them changing their question to be one that can be on-topic in the case where there are no answers to the question yet.  It doesn't actually seem like they'd be able to get out of their ban otherwise, ever -- and that doesn't seem very fair to tell a user.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199779/discussion-on-answer-by-george-stocker-why-is-this-question-off-topic).