# How can I improve this question's reception?

Tags: support, specific-question, quality-improvement

Could someone hazard a guess as to why people are downvoting my question:

*[How do I convert 'Single' to binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58036294/how-to-convert-single-to-binary)*

I took care to explain the problem clearly and in detail, as well as describe what I tried and why it didn't work.

Comment: Related: [Why isn't providing feedback mandatory on downvotes, and why are ideas suggesting such shot down?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436/1288408)

Comment: Another good resource: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389630/ive-asked-a-poorly-received-question-what-do-i-do-now (general, not specific to your question in main; I’m afraid I can’t give you feedback on that at the moment).

Comment: @InteXX for the 1000th time, downvotes are not rudeness.

Comment: @InteXX What's incredibly rude is assuming things about people you don't know.  Have you ever considered that people refrain from commenting because of responses like yours?

Comment: I'm sorry. I am not as annoyed by you per se as it might seem. Just annoyed by constant mentions of moderation "rudeness".

Comment: @InteXX Thanks. Some background: this is how some users react to comments on down or close votes. Warning: not safe for work. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366733/1288408 It's one reason why commenting is discouraged.

Comment: Those were "this is not useful" votes, one of the basic ways we get contributors to focus on questions that can turn into useful Q+A with lasting value.  And for you to edit and clarify your goal.  An implicit problem with a question like that is that another programmer might think it is something they might to want to do as well.  They shouldn't.  I provided some bullets to help you shoot your left foot, hopefully enough for you to decide you don't want to do that either.  You can get real help by explaining why you decided to do this so somebody can provide a practical solution.

Comment: @HansPassant ~ Got it. I see now that I've bitten off more than I'm going to want to chew with that Single-to-Binary conversion effort. Good replies, thank you.

Comment: @ModusTollens ~ `Why isn't providing feedback mandatory on downvotes ... ` Good one. I think you've managed to get me to change my tune, by that single reference. I especially like the first bullet point on the accepted answer.

Comment: @Daedalus ~ `Have you ever considered that people refrain from commenting because of responses like yours` That assumes that my responses came before the failure to comment, which would be incorrect.

Comment: Nah, what it assumes is that users who downvote have experience with backlash to their explanations (as Modus Tollens linked to an example). They just assumed you'd react the same, and you didn't fail to go on the offensive.

Comment: @StoryTeller ~ Yes, that was quite a post, wasn't it? Anyway, among the suggestions for proper handling of a comment requirement when down voting is to make them anonymous. I also encountered a comment by someone on one of the many Q&As I've been reading tonight on this who reasoned that the retaliation fear is exaggerated. That makes sense. I know I stated earlier that I may have changed my tune on this, but I'm still on the fence. In general I remain convinced that far worse long term damage is done by allowing these "drive-by" down votes.

Comment: @StoryTeller ~ `offensive` Er...  that'd be defensive.

Comment: No, offensive. Those curators being "rude" *is* an offensive slur. You weren't slighted, your content was *curated*. You went up in arms over it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You say

> Unfortunately, however, it returns inaccurate results.

Inaccurate how? For what values is it inaccurate and what values would it display if it were accurate?

In addition, since Single is a floating point type, what range did you want this to work under? Does the algorithm need to cope with fractional values and/or really large values? You mention in passing that

> The single-argument overload returns scientific notation

Are we supposed to conclude that the binary output should not? Have you thought about why the decimal printing of Single uses scientific notation? Even if we stick with base 10, how would you display 1<sup>30</sup> or 1<sup>-30</sup> without scientific notation and without either inaccuracy or displaying lots of meaningless digits?

The above questions are the sort of things you need to address in your question in order to make it answerable.

Comment: Thank you, this explains it very well. FYI I've edited the question to indicate expected and actual values. I've also decided to abandon the effort due to the extra complexities introduced by attempting to do this with a floating point number. (This whole thing has been a good learning experience.)