# How can I improve this question's reception? (Part II)

Tags: support, specific-question, quality-improvement

I asked this question, which resulted in a few downvotes:

[How to convert Single to Binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58036294/722393)

The downvotes came without any comments, so I was unable to discern how to improve the question. Thus I entered this question on META:

[How can I improve this question's reception?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/389642/722393)

The META question was answered satisfactorily, so I accepted the answer and edited my original SO question accordingly.

However, the downvotes are still coming in.

What further can I do to stem the outgoing tide?

Comment: In the end, comments are individual opinions. One of the reasons to downvote a post is _"I do not find this useful"_. There were some comments in your other question and in your question in main that indicated why some users might have found your question less than useful. Beyond that, the only way to know why a user voted like they did is to to perform a bit of mind-reading, which sadly we can't.

Comment: There is no way to "prevent" users from voting as they wish, as long as they are not performing vote fraud. And "silent" voting is encouraged, up or down. FYI, I didn't vote on this question, hence my comments.

Comment: @yivi ~ `perform a bit of mind-reading, which sadly we can't` I'm workin' on it.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect

Comment: I see that now in your question in main you added two language tags. That's very, very rarely useful or appropriate.

Comment: As gnat linked.. what you're seeing is possibly a vicious form of the meta effect. Some curators want to 'punish'people by hurting their rep, and downvote the main content when they encounter something they don't like on meta (your first approach could have triggered that. It's not okay, mind you... But possible). The logic used though is 'by linking your question on meta, you expose is to more people, so you see more votes on it'. It could be a bit of both of those things, hard to say

Comment: @yivi ~ Aha. Is there a standard way, then, of indicating that I'm not picky about which .NET programming language the answerer uses?

Comment: That doesn't seem to be a good question for SO, since there is no way to judge the _correctness_ of the answers. Two answers could be _equally_ good, but on different languages. A question like that would not be adequately scoped, IMO. (Which could also translate to downvotes, for the question may not be considered clear enough).

Comment: @Patrice ~ A butterfly floats...

Comment: @yivi ~ `there is no way to judge the correctness of the answers` Hm, but there is. A correct answer in C# will convert to VB and run, and vice-versa, with the same results per language.

Comment: I'm  not all that clear on why it got so many downvotes.  It's not that unusual to wish to serialize a FP value, though yes, it's probably better/safer to stringify it and convert back at the peer.   Still,  users vote as they wish.....:)

Comment: One possibility: you still haven't included *why* you're trying to do that, which makes it hard for people to identify [XY problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and provide better overall solutions.

Comment: @InteXX ..and FP format mismatch stings like a bee:)

Comment: @MartinJames ~ `stings like a bee` Yes, I believe it does :-)

Comment: @jonrsharpe ~ Good suggestion. I've edited the question.

Comment: *"in case I may need this functionality at some point in the future"* is pretty much an anti-reason, both in terms of SO questions (where general curiosity or speculation leave us without concrete success criteria) and programming generally (YAGNI).

Comment: @jonrsharpe ~ `leave us without concrete success criteria` Isn't the ability/inability to serialize a `Single` to a binary string sufficient success/failure criteria unto itself, regardless of the presence of a specific business requirement at this time?

Comment: @gnat ~ `meta-effect` That makes sense.

Comment: @yivi ~ `you added two language tags` In your opinion, is it better to have *no* language tags than two language tags?

Comment: It's better to have **one** language tag, unless your question is really language-agnostic. Those questions are much rarer, and are not usually linked to one specific framework. There is even a tag for that.

Comment: @yivi ~ I took advantage of your escape clause 'usually'  ;-)

Comment: As you wish, but if other users feel your question is not correctly scoped, just adding one tag won't immunize you from votes. I have no interest in .NET, so I won't make any judgements on your question on main anyway. Good luck!

Comment: The problem is: you're still asking an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/369403). Essentially, the question behind the question is: how is a Single represented in binary memory? If you'd understand that, you'd understand the answer and the results you got. However, that's likely a duplicate.

Comment: @jonrsharpe ~ I don't know what other X problem I can describe. I have no business requirement for it at the moment, but I wouldn't be surprised if one showed up e.g. next week. I'm just building out my own internal framework, that's all, and this series (`Byte`,`Short`,`Integer`,`Long`,`Single`) seemed like one I ought to have on hand. The `Single` has turned out to be too complex to want to work out, though, so I've decided to drop it from the list for now.

Comment: @ErikA ~ Yes, I see that now. Would that I could delete all of this and pretend it never happened, but that wouldn't be right either. Some good folks have put some love into this, and I wouldn't want to kick 'em in the shin for it.

Comment: Yup, this one is a tough break. Best just leave it be as-is imo, substantial edits to change the scope would invalidate the answer. Btw, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) is a great source for information on essential programming stuff like this, and more extensive than a Stack Overflow answer can be.

Comment: @ErikA ~ `a tough break` Can't win 'em all... :-) I'll have to study that Wiki page some more when I can. There's a lot of info there.

Comment: "The downvotes came without any comments, so I was unable to discern how to improve the question" -- this isn't really true. A downvote means "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful" Thus a downvote, by itself is _some_ indication as to what's wrong.

Comment: @Flimzy ~ `Thus a downvote by itself is some indication as to what's wrong` Not much of one, though, if so. I refer you to the first comment in this thread, by `yivi`.

Answer (score 7):

Question does not show sesnible research - since it is marked "language neutral" and .Net it implies that you've at least checked how problem described with words you've used is usually solved in most common .Net languages C# and VB.Net.

Doing basic search https://www.bing.com/search?q=convert+float+to+binary+c%23 shows that everyone uses `BitConverter` - so naturally everyone who reads your question expects to see at least some information why regular approach does not fit. Since none is found and there is some strange code shown its fair to downvote for lack of research.

Additionally note that the question starts with "in case I may need this functionality at some point in the future" - this is common sign of a not practical problem. Opening a question that way changes perception to start on a negative side. Unfortunately that feeling does not change much while reading through the question - after reading it several times it still unclear what you want to see as result: it hard to see how showing QWORD value converted by calculator  is related to `System.Single` (which is DWORD), number you start with does not fit into precision of `System.Single` (which you presumably researched about too)... That should lead to at least "unclear what you are asking" votes to close, but also can be reason for donwvotes.

Overall you essentially requested everyone to look at your question but question is confusing and shows very strange effort to solve non-practical problem.

Comment: I'm more than willing to consider this, but I'd like to discuss it with you a bit first. I have some questions.

Comment: You say it's unclear what I'm asking, but the last sentence is `Given these, how may we reliably convert a Single value to a binary string?` I'm confused. How is that unclear?

Comment: You say it's unclear what I want to see as a result. Doesn't the result of the `Assert.AreEqual` call indicate this?

Comment: You say the question doesn't show research, but if that's truly a problem why do we find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/677373/722393) with 32 upvotes? (FWIW, I did search for about an hour before posting and found nothing but the code I included. Granted I searched with StartPage for 'convert single to binary' and not 'convert float to binary', so that may have had something to do with it.)

Comment: FYI I edited the question just now to remove the 'in case I may need this...' and to provide a prior-research link to the answer that inspired the code.

Comment: `DWORD` is `Integer` (32-bit). `QWord` is `Long` (64-bit). The starting number is an `Integer` cast to a `Single`: `Dim nSingle = CSng(1361294667)`.

Comment: `non-practical problem` I disagree—I'm building out my internal framework and I want to have a means for serializing a `Single` into binary text ready to go when I encounter a business requirement for doing so. I'm preparing in advance for the day that need arises—I don't want to put it off until the last possible moment, when the requirements call for it, I'm under the gun of a heavy deadline, and I have to stop what I'm doing and get bogged down fighting something I should have done earlier. In other words, I'm trying to stave off technical debt. That's only prudent, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: I'm not trying to scrap with you on these—if you can show me further where I might be mistaken on these points, I hope you'll do so. I'm only trying to invite more detailed discussion.

Comment: p.s. The `language-agnostic` tag is intended to invite answers in either C# or VB. If I tag it as VB.NET I'll sharply limit the avenues for a successful answer. It doesn't matter to me which language is used for that—I can read either.

Comment: p.s. The "strange effort" in the question is the concept of successive division, a technique used to convert numbers to binary strings. You can find an example [here](https://youtu.be/rsxT4FfRBaM?t=443).

Comment: I'm not saying you did not do research (also using number that can't be represented as `Single` as an example of `Single` value hints at such possibility) - I'm saying that the question does not explain what exactly you need that is different from standard answer to such question. You claim you need to do serialization but noone does it by converting numbers to bytes.... so explaining why/what exactly you need that is different would make question much better. And "binary text" you mentioned in comment is not a concept that is common - again example of what you looking for would help.

Comment: As for code shown in the post - it is obvious what it is... but it makes no sense for reasonable floating point values like 10^100 or 0.5 or 10^(-100)... and the fact that you pick number that can't be represented as `Single` did not help much with explaining what you want.

Comment: `Dim nSingle = CSng(1361294667)` `nSingle` equals `1.36129472E+09`. That sure looks like a `Single` to me  ;-)

Comment: @InteXX Pointing to a 10 year old question and saying "it's poorly researched too" is not a good idea. That comes from when the site was young and the rules were much less strictly enforced since there were fewer questions overall. Now the site gets 7k+ questions a day, and questions which don't meet the quality bar are more stringently pruned.

Comment: @InteXX could you please help me to understand what part of "number you start with does not fit into precision of System.Single" is unclear? As person with 3K points I expect you to be well aware of floating point numbers in general - so I used "precision" as in "allows precisely represent value without loss of significant digits"... maybe I should have clarified that word with link to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872544/what-range-of-numbers-can-be-represented-in-a-16-32-and-64-bit-ieee-754-syste (or similar)… but that seemed unnecessary

Comment: InteXX - just to add to @HereticMonkey comment - your claim essentially is "this question is *poorly researched* too but over 10 years some people found it *useful*" - indeed there are poorly researched but useful on-topic questions. So far yours yet to prove that it is useful to enough people (or even attract attention on its own). Note so that keeping poorly researched questions is problematic for exact reason you linked to - they tend to be used as "this is good question" examples - so active moderation of such questions is needed (and downvotes are part of it).

Comment: @HereticMonkey ~ Fair 'nuff. Thanks for reading.

Comment: `help me to understand` I've a surprise for you :-) I've only started learning about floating-point numbers as a result of this issue. Prior to this, they've been a complete mystery to me—now they're only a partial mystery.

Comment: `just to add to @HereticMonkey comment` Got it, makes sense.

Comment: FYI I've chained my binary conversion extension methods together—`Byte.ToBinary()` calls `Short.ToBinary()`, `Short.ToBinary` calls `Integer.ToBinary()`, and on up the stack (thus the `Select Case` at the end to evaluate the number size and determine the length of the string). I only ran into trouble when I hit `Single`. I've learned through all of this, then, that a floating-point number can't be reliably converted to binary—it just ain't gonna happen. I wish somebody had pointed that out early on, but them's the breaks I guess.

Comment: @InteXX you use some very specific meaning of "converted to binary" which is probably where all confusion and at least some downvotes started. `Single` is stored as 32 bits which are very well defined and trivial to be represented as sequence of 32 zero and ones - as bit array or string... I'm not exactly sure at which point you could/should have realized that and clarify what you are looking for... maybe answer you got could be an indication that "converted to binary" words you used are understood completely differently from what you mean using them...

Comment: I appreciate you sticking with me through all of this. You surprise me with your statement `trivial to be represented as sequence of 32 zero and ones`. Everything I've seen indicates that it's not possible to do accurately, including [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html#682). I must be missing something somewhere.

Comment: @InteXX I think you looking at it backward - `Single` is a finite set of values from real numbers that is obtained by particular (IEEE 754) interpretation of 32bits. 1/3 is not in that set as well as 1361294667 - one can pick a value from that set that is close to number you want to see but it will be different number. The claim is just that - tiny finite countable set of `Single` values can't have one-to-one relation to uncountable infinite set of all real numbers.

Comment: Now THAT's a mouthful! I can see I've got a long way to go on this. I only wish there were more time in a day. Thank you for helping me to understand this better.