# Can we get an update regarding the closing/reopening experiment?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, vote-to-reopen

Half a month has almost passed since [the experiment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388313/experiment-ended-closing-and-reopening-happens-at-3-votes-for-the-next-30-day) ended and I know Shog left a couple of comments on the post since it ended but it was mentioned that the results would be compiled over the following week yet we've heard nothing at all.

Can we get an update regarding it?

---

<sup>This question was motivated by me casting a reopen vote and realising I'd need another 4 more. Not to mention that the close votes queue sits at a hefty 8.4K.</sup>

Comment: Maybe Shog wants to include a thorough analysis of the depression afterwards (when people realised it's now 5 votes again). Or they are discussing if they should remain with 3 votes permanently.

Comment: There's a lot that went on last week. I wouldn't be surprised if it's bumped out again.

Comment: 8.4K is probably underestimated quite a bit, this is just a fake value displayed to make us feel better

Comment: @GeorgeStocker can clarify what you mean for us folks who missed whatever went on?

Comment: @Script47 No, unfortunately I can't.

Comment: I'm wrapping it up. As George notes, there's been some... Unfortunate stuff... That I've been trying to lend a hand with behind the scenes. Not what I'd planned, but so it goes.

Comment: On the bright side? I got to do a before - during - after comparison this way. Which is nice for throwing the effects into sharp relief.

Comment: @Shog9 - I know its a brief answer, but shouldn't your comment simply be the answer here? I mean, this post is all about you :)

Comment: I have had my coffee yet, @travis. Comments are nice for those situations where you're *pretty sure* you're not just typing a stream of profane gibberish, but not... Quite... 100% sure.

Comment: Oh, no coffee yet? Sorry @Shog9, I know how that goes. I haven't had mine either, so perhaps I should also forgo commenting.

Comment: @410 the experiment affected all users. Therefore surely the outcome of said experiment is of importance to all users.

Comment: It looks like *something* significant is being planned, which may well be related (I hope): [Can't talk about the specifics just yet, but... SUPER excited about the work being done to improve the question asking and curation processes on Stack Overflow. Haven't been this excited to go to work in years.](https://twitter.com/shog9/status/1172949564225019904) -Shog9

Comment: Just want to give a public shout-out for all of @Shog9's hard work on this while a lot of other things are going on behind the scenes, too. Thanks for your patience everyone! 

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I'm about 90% done with the report (percentage calculated with fair dice; other techniques are used in the actual report). I'd hoped to publish something here sooner, but several urgent situations have arisen privately and I've been trying to assist my team in resolving them before they overshadow happier projects such as this.

Sorry for the delay; I do believe the results will be worth the wait.

Comment: These past few months have not been looking specifically positive for SE. This, however, gives me a lot of hope. Thank you for being open about the reasons why it's delayed instead of just ignoring it, and in general, thank you for being awesome (and not just here, but you handle a lot of things just perfectly).

Comment: I certainly don't handle anything perfectly; indeed, there are many things I don't handle well *at all.* But the beauty of working remotely is that very few people can hear me as I stomp around my house cursing.

Comment: (not mentioned in deleted comments under experiment announcement) I'd like to learn about amount of "hard" question bans vs softer forms of throttling inexperienced askers via rolling rate limits - was there a noticeable impact of the experiment on that? In one recent discussion I saw complaint that [some users slip into ban too quickly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/389629/839601); in theory this can be attributed to closures / deletions happening too late to let rolling rate system properly kick in and I'm interested in data to help see if this is so or not

Comment: Slight dip at the start of the experiment, but probably just coincidence - the # of people encountering bans fluctuates wildly all the time, and I would expect it to take  months for a change like this to have any noticeable effect. @gnat