# Can I edit a question so that it basically becomes a different one?

Tags: support, editing-help

A question I asked received a downvote, and got closed, because it is out of scope (not related to coding), and I got a ban on asking questions as a result.

Stack Overflow suggests that I edit the question and make it useful. I don't see a way to improve it, without changing it completely. Is that OK? But I am afraid that the one answer and few comments it received would make no sense anymore.

Comment: If it already received an answer, you cannot edit the question to become something else. (If it _hadn't_ received an answer, some users believe it would be fine for you to be able to edit and try to use it as a last-resort chance to get out of the ban -or dig yourself deeper into it-; while others disagree, because it would be circumventing the rules).

Comment: There will be other questions you have that are also off topic. Getting downvoted on one question doesn't get you a question ban; many bad questions get you a question ban. That includes deleted questions (which I suspect you have several of).

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389624/what-are-the-reasons-for-not-allowing-people-to-drastically-edit-off-topic-unan

Comment: @Larnu I have only one deleted question (for a reason other than being out of scope), and this downvoted one. The other questions have 0 votes, and they are already very specific, thus hard to improve. Am I stuck now?

Comment: It's possible that you have other deleted questions you forgot about. With your currently non-deleted questions, unless the one deleted question has a terrible negative score, I think it's unlikely anyone would get q-banned. A moderator may provide you with a list of your deleted questions, to see if there is anything there worth salvaging.

Comment: "and I got a ban on asking questions as a result." - You were not question banned due to one single question that was downvoted.  In order to be question banned you had to have asked multiple questions, that were downvoted, users are not question banned due to a single bad question.  Even if you have multiple questions that have received 0 votes, it still takes more than a single downvote to a single question, to be question banned.  You might not have any recently deleted questions, but they do exist, and a moderator can list them for you.

Comment: @yivi I searched my email. Only two messages from Stack overflow with title "Your question has been closed". I opened the first deleted question from the message, and found that it has a score of 0.

Comment: Still, it's likely you have more deleted questions. Maybe they were downvoted and then deleted, but not closed. That you cannot remember or find links to them is not evidence of their absence, but simply absence of evidence. Sadly, users below 10k cannot readily search for their deleted posts. Never understood that limitation, to be honest.

Comment: @yivi ok. Is there a procedure to ask a moderator to list my deleted questions for me?

Comment: Flag one of your posts with "in need of moderator intervention", and ask to be provided a list of your deleted questions to attempt editing them into shape. Or just leave this post up, and sooner or later (usually sooner) a mod will come around and post a list for you.

Comment: Once a user is close to the threshold of being question banned, when they submit a question, they are warned of their status while submitting that question.  Your last question that is closed and downvoted, has an accepted answer, and thus the question cannot be changed.  If you were to change the question, and invalidate the answer, edit would just be reversed and the original question would be restored.

Comment: @yivi I see. Thanks a lot.
and thanks to everyone else who left a comment.

Comment: @SecurityHound yes, I see. I believe I am kind of stuck now, because most of my questions either have answers, or are deleted but I don't remember them. I will try to ask a moderator to list my deleted questions, and then see what to do.

Comment: The canonical is *[Exit strategies for “chameleon questions”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478)*.