# I answered a question which was replaced by a totally different one

Tags: discussion, edits, rollbacks

I answered a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49207485/custom-post-type-import-in-wordpress) about topic X.

When I came back, cause of a comment, the question was 100% replaced and now was asking about topic Y. So my answer (which is/was the only one) is now totally irrelevant.

When I talk about 100% replacement I mean 100% replacement of the text, no slight change of topic or adding additional questions.

In the question history a saw that topic Y was the original and got rollbacked.

1. The author created question about Y (years ago) ([Rev. 2](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/49207485/2))
2. The author had changed his own question to something else (Topic X, [Rev 3](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/49207485/3))
3. Added a bounty on this revision
4. I answered to Rev 3, about X (first and only answer to this question)
5. somebody rollbacked the question to Rev 2 (the original question).

How to handle such case? Keep the new question, revert to the original, or something else?

Comment: It's really frowned upon to completely change a question. I suspect the OP is question banned, and thus as they couldn't ask a new question, they completely changed an old one and bountied to get it attention.

Comment: @JeanneDark the first edit invalidated 2 comments, the rollback invalidated the answer

Comment: I would suggest that the question be flagged, the bounty removed (by a moderator), and the OP told they should be posting a new question.

Comment: If you think your answer is useful for future users, delete it and ask a new question which you then self-answer.

Comment: @Jeanne Dark, no not really. I'm talking about a 100% text replacement not a slight change of topic or additional questions added

Comment: The correct course of action would be to delete your answer and flag the question for moderator attention so that they can lock it in the original form. If you want to preserve your answer, ask a new question and then self-answer

Comment: You missed the part where the OP (here) answered **after** the edit, @JeanneDark .

Comment: At the very minimum the OP is circumventing the minimal waiting period before offering a bounty. The question should not be reverted back to X, that would be unfair to every user who waits before offering a bounty. (there might be even fishier reasons, but that's what we can see as normal users)

Comment: You raise a good point there, @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz , I hadn't considered that.

Comment: (I'm voting to reopen this question because the situation here is a bit more complicated than in the dupe)

Comment: They didn't change it back, @JeanneDark, it was rolled back by the community.

Comment: @Dharman That's seems unreasonable. We should not have to look at post histories prior to answering a post that has no Answers on it.

Comment: @Scratte No, it is not necessary to check the history and this situation is not the fault of the user who answered. However the edit from Y to X should have never been made and it is unfair if the OP gets away with such fishy manoeuvrers.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz We don't moderate users. We moderate posts. If the X Question/Answer pair is fine, then it's a fine addition to the repository no matter how it came to be. The user is unlikely to get equally "lucky" continuing to use the trick.. if that's what it's called.

Comment: @Scratte with this logic, you can let suspended users post questions

Comment: @Scratte What's the point then of a waiting period before a bounty or a question ban?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz No. That is not at all the same thing. Moderators moderate users and determines if that account may or may not interact with the site. It's not for us to determine that on individual posts. We're not the user police and we do not hand out punishments. We just look at posts..

Comment: I really like [Jean-Francois's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/389661/6045800) on this matter

Comment: @Scratte in truth us users do very much also determine if a user can perform certain actions. If a user makes multiple posts that receive downvotes (from us users) it's our votes that end up with the user getting a post ban. Our thoughts/opinions on a user's content can certainly affect what they can (or can't) do on the site.

Comment: @Larnu We still just moderate the posts.. unless someone downvotes the *user*, which is frowned upon. If a user has several really bad posts, then the system reacts to that. But it's not for us to go through user accounts and downvote the lot.

Comment: I don't disagree that we don't moderate the user, @Scratte , but that doesn't also mean that my votes don't contribute to what privileges another user has. Also if I stumble across a second (or 3rd) post from the same user during my **normal use** of the site that I have previously downvoted doesn't mean I won't downvote the others; though my vote is always based on the content of the post, not because it's the same user.

Comment: @Larnu That's the way it should be done :) Your vote has a *side effect* on the user only if it's a recurring pattern which you don't and should not take into account when you vote. You can downvote a post by Jon Skeet and your vote will not result in a ban for that user :) What I'm reacting to here is the notion that *this user did it wrong* so therefore we need to invalidate the current Answer, which in my opinion is very much directly moderating the user.

Comment: Yes, we can't make the decision on this specific scenario, @Scratte, I agree. I can't talk for other users, but I have flagged the question for moderator attention as they can make a more informed decision.

Comment: Since the question was already rolled back, you can [repost the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1723351e-c76c-42e3-8d3d-dc26ce53745c/view-source) and answer it with [your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69553795/revisions)

Comment: Cross site: *[Exit strategies for "chameleon questions"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/)*

Comment: FTR: I found the question when looking through active questions, I read it and then I read comments, noticed it was an abuse of question ban, so I rolled it back. Then I started to wonder what to do about the answer... but as I was a little clueless and out of time I didn't flag it. The correct action IMHO would be to flag it and ask moderators to delete the question. This seems to have already happened.

Comment: @lamu Based on your first comment above, does it make sense that a user can be question banned, yet can still offer a bounty on an existing question? It would seem more logical that if the user is question banned then the privilege to offer bounties should also be withheld.

Comment: Yes, those are two totally separate things. Also, it's larnu, not lamu (CC@Larnu)

Comment: *I* could be question banned, @skomisa , are you saying I should not be able to bounty, even though I have over 60k rep?

Comment: @KevinB Got it. And my apologies to lamu and larnu for the misdirection.

Comment: @skomisa We want people to improve their existing questions as part of getting out of the question ban. A banned user using a bounty to get more attention on a question they've fixed wouldn't be a problem. (Putting a bounty on someone else's question also wouldn't be a problem.) I think this is just a really weird case.

Answer (score 10):

Firstly, lets start off by saying that there was nothing wrong with your action(s) of answering the question at the point you did. We, as users, are not expected to look at a question's history and see that the context of it has not just been changed significantly (such as in the event of an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info)) but that it has been changed completely with no overlap at all.

The real problem stems from several things:

1. The OP of the question (in question) completely changed the context of the question.
2. Bountied said question *immediately* (2 minutes 37 seconds) after the edit was made.
3. Another user in the community rolled back the edit without considering that an answer to the *new™* question had been posted.

##### Point 1:

Generally such actions are frowned upon. Questions can be edited to add more context, or even correct the goal posts based on the comments (such as in the aforementioned XY Problem scenario), but this should certainly **not** be done after answers are received. No answers, however, had been received at the point of the complete context change, so many of the "standards" the community apply to such edits don't apply.

As has been mentioned in the comments, [Jean-François Fabre's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/389661/2029983) however, touches on this well; they explain that really the question can only be completely amended in the minutes after it has been posted and only if it has had no interactions. If there have been interactions this poses issues on things like comments.

If the user isn't question banned, then they should have posted a new question and waited to bounty it when they were allowed to; if that was their actions I do feel that there actions were in "the wrong".

If, however, they are questions banned then I think the OP would have been best here the flag the comments on the question as "no longer needed", wait for them to be deleted, and then completely edit; so as not to cause said confusion.

##### Point 2

This I think was wrong. There is a reason that new questions aren't allowed to be bountied straight away, and the edit made the question a *new™* question. There's no way to *stop* the user from bountying it, but I feel it is "underhanded". I would suggest that someone who noticed the complete context change edit (the person in point 3) should have flagged the question to perhaps have the bounty removed.

##### Point 3

These actions were certainly wrong, as it invalidated an answer; these are "higher class citizens" that comments, and take priority, even if the answer is newer. Unfortunately I don't feel that rolling back to the complete edit is now correct, as an unfortunate chain of events has occurred that (in my opinion) puts means states of the question are "invalid". What should have happened here is what I said in point 2: the user should have flagged the question, *not* just rolled it back.

#### What happens now?

From us users? Nothing. We can't, I don't feel, solve this problem now. Like I said, I feel both states are "invalid". The old question has relevance for the comments, and (like mentioned) generally changing a question like this is frowned upon. The *new™* question, however, is valid for your answer, so should also be there.

Only a moderator can really solve this problem now. I, personally, have flagged the question, citing this question in said flag, and I am sure others have to. If the user isn't banned, I would expect the moderator to tell them to use the new question "feature". If they aren't then perhaps advise them to get the question cleaned up first. The person that did the rollback should also be reminded to not perform them in such a scenario and flag for moderator attention.

I would *guess*, however, that the end result will be the bounty removed, comments cleaned up, and the question reverted to the one *you* answered. That is the cleanest solution in my opinion.

Comment: I'm glad you brought up point 2– I missed that at first; using this approach, whether intentionally or not, the question OP was able to circumvent the new post bounty timer, which isn't ok.

Answer (score 0):

The situation here is a bit more complicated as the usual "edits should not invalidate existing answers".

I don't think the question should be changed back to X, because the OP should not have made the edit from Y to X in the first place.

- At the very minimum they circumvent the minimum waiting time to offer a bounty which is unfair to every user who patiently waited to offer a bounty for their new question.
- the edit is abusing the edit mechanism. Edits are to improve a question, to add additional information or clarify, not to completely change the topic.
- Even fishier reasons for the edit might be at play. It would need a moderator to check if there might be something like a question ban involved.

---

**What should we do with the answer?**

If you think your answer is useful for future users, delete it and ask a new question which you then self-answer (as the question was posted under [CC BY-SA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creative_Commons_license#Seven_regularly_used_licenses), you can even safely reuse the same text if you link to the revision).

Comment: Since the question was edited before it was answered... why was the edit itself problematic? **If** the "new" question were good and no answers were invalidated in the process, wouldn't the end result be a desirable one, even if the process involved circumventing a q-ban?

Comment: @yivi If you edit a question to make it into an entirely different one, then you invalidate all references to the original question - so even if there are no existing answers, there might be discussion about the question on meta or off-site, there could be people who bookmarked it in case it ever received an answer, there could be people who had begun working on an answer to it but didn't get there in time. And so on.

Comment: @kaya3 That seems entirely irrelevant. What matters is that we build a library of high quality Q&A. Offsite incoming links are quite irrelevant (even more so on an **unanswered question**). Meta discussions can always link to a revision. Nobody was "on the process of writing an answer" to a very much abandoned question. We are grasping at straws simply to keep a user down because they did "wrong". Yeah, I get it. Rules are rules. But there **reasons** for rules. In this case, (if the new question were good) forcing a rollback does not seem to serve any purpose.

Comment: @yivi Indeed, but as samcarter proposes, if X and the OP's answer to X would have been a valuable addition to SO, then OP could ask and self-answer it themselves. So enforcing the rules here does not result in any detriment to the quality of SO as a library of Q&As.

Comment: @kaya3 It can result in actual harm. Because if the q-banned had edited their question into something of good quality, without any bytes being harmed in the process, we robbed them of an opportunity of getting out of the ban and adding better content. Simply because _"thou shall not edit your questions into new questions"_. I agree with that rule, because it makes sense not to invalidate answers and disrespect fellow users. But on an unanswered, abandoned question? What's the frikking harm in that? None. At best you are pushing the user into creating a new account. That sounds great.

Comment: @kaya3 It does.. For many reasons. One being users reluctant to post Questions. The other is that any new Question must link to the old as per the license agreement. There's no reason to remove a post just to ask the same one.